# Zend DB Table update affected rows are zero

Tags: zend-db-table

I am updating the db table using below code but it does not seem to working fine.

```
$model = new Admin_Model_DbTable_SmsTemplate();
$where =   $model->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);
$model->getDbTable()->update(array('content'=>$content), $where);
```

what is the error in this code as it is giving affected rows zero.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using Zend_Db_table IN ZF1. 
You can achieve it like this:-

```
    $db=Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $model = new  Admin_Model_DbTable_SmsTemplate($db);
    $where = 'id = ' . $id;
    $model->update(array('content'=>$content), $where);
```

OR

```
$db=Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$where = 'id = ' . $id;
$db->update('YourTableName', array('content = ?' => $content,),
            $where
           );
```

And the adapter will do quote work for you.